# Color x Grids in tables

Tags: tables

I have been trying to reproduce a table with two uncommon features.

1. Grey first row Header
2. Two last columns with extra row.

First I managed to do the extra row, but if I try to put the color in the first row I lose some of the grid lines around the table.
Any quick fixes? Thanks in advance.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray} %(if I comment this line its OK but no color)
{Path}& A(2)  & $(A(2)-100)^+$   & Probability  & Payoff $\times$ Probability  \\ \hline
                  &                        &  &  &  \\ \hline
          &              &  &  &  \\ \hline
           &            &  &  &  \\ \hline
           &        &  &  &  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}                                                                              & Sum & 13.99707 \\ \cline{4-5} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Your code works, (apart from not being a MWE). The fact, that you don't see the grid lines is just a `.pdf` viewer issue. If you zoom in or print your table, you will detect the grid lines!